# Why are numbers converted to dates when uploading an Excel catalog to Ariba?

Tags: sap-ariba

Uploading a catalog file to Ariba has always been a huge pain for me. It always seems to have errors. The last time I tried, however, it took the file on the first try, which was amazing.  This time, no such luck. It seems like the Excel to CIF converter is changing number values to dates, which causes the file to not pass validation.  Even if I download the previous working file and plug in the new data, it still doesn't work.

Upon validation, it complains that the number of items in the file doesn't match the value in the header (because it changed that from 25 to 1900-01-25.) It lets me edit the header, but when I change the ITEMCOUNT value  to 25 and try validating again, it then tells me there are 50 errors!  Two for every item line in the file!  One says, "Missing value for required attribute on type money" and the other says, "Money amount is not valid for attribute: amount value 1901-03-13 21:36:00" (date stamp value varies).

Any ideas? I've tried saving my file in different .xls flavors (95 vs. 97/2000, etc.) I even tried downloading their CIF template, adding my data, and uploading.  No luck.